# How do I add general error handling into my React app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently building a React app which does a lot of server communication. If a server error occurs, I want to display the error to the user in a general way, e.g. an overlay with the error message.

### Using container components

In my reducers, I return something like this:

`{
  type: "LIST_POSTS_ERROR",
  loading: false,
  error: {
    msg: "An error occurred"
  }
}`

Obviously, my container components are redux aware. In the `render()` function, I could check, if the current state has a property `error` and if so, I would render the error message. Oddly, in every container component, I would have to check the current state and might have duplicated code in every container component.

### A more general approach

What am I looking for is a more general approach. Something that knows about all the states and displays the error message automatically if the current state contains an error. Think of it like an interceptor for errors. Of course, this component would not belong to a route, so I am wondering if this is even possible?

**How do you do error handling in your React app? I would love to know your approach!**

Comment: This seems more like a JavaScript question than react specific, why not return a function that creates a new Error, and then assign that error properties you would like to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app, I've a action called `handleError` which will trigger a `toast` component in my app.

You can `dispatch` this action at the time of error. Like, you can `dispatch` it in the `.catch()` of the `Promise`.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution! I created a new action that gets dispatched and created a new reducer for that. My goal is to have another ContainerComponent that knows about the error state. So I created a ContainerComponent. However, the ContainerComponent does not get called because it never gets initialised. Where do you initialise your `toast` Component?

Comment: Exactly. Make the component listen to the  error action and show relevant error using that component!

Comment: Hm. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/jonicious/06dcb2db3a6fb8a496f81baa3390170e

Comment: Looks clean to me!

Comment: I think, the problem is that React or Redux do not know that this component is actually being used.

Comment: Insert this component into your react

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? I am importing it and can see it in my source maps.

Comment: Hups, sorry for being stupid :D Added and (of course) it worked ✨

Comment: That's Awesome. Follow the same pattern everywhere. Abstract out the common functionalities and build a component for that and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something similar for my App. So fire a dispatch on catch or >=400 response to set a string(your api response) in state and connect this value to your component.

Next, after maybe 4-5 seconds fire a dispatch to clear that value, so your message would go away. This you can implement in your login screens or your post API calls.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Do you have to do anything extra to initialise your component? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057872/how-do-i-add-general-error-handling-into-my-react-app/40058298?noredirect=1#comment67396734_40058298